# inner join slow performance

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table offers that has over 100k rows so the below query is very slow (4sec - average).

```
SELECT cat1.id AS cat1id, 
    cat1.title_gr AS title, 
    cat1.order

    FROM categories_groups_cat1 AS cat1

    INNER JOIN 
      ( SELECT categories_id, categories_groups_cat1_id FROM
        categories_vs_groups
        GROUP BY categories_groups_cat1_id ) AS vs
    ON vs.categories_groups_cat1_id=cat1.id

    INNER JOIN 
      ( SELECT id, title_gr FROM
        categories
        GROUP BY title_gr ) AS cats
    ON cats.id=vs.categories_id

   INNER JOIN 
      ( SELECT category_gr FROM
        offers
        GROUP BY category_gr ) AS offers
    ON offers.category_gr=cats.title_gr

    GROUP BY cat1.id
    ORDER BY cat1.order ASC
```

table offers

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` text NOT NULL,
`description` text NOT NULL,
`image` text NOT NULL,
`price` float NOT NULL,
`start_price` float NOT NULL,
`brand` text NOT NULL
`category_gr` text NOT NULL
```

table categories_groups_cat1

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`order` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title_gr` text NOT NULL
```

table categories_vs_groups

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`categories_groups_cat1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL
```

table categories

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title_gr` char(255) NOT NULL
```

I try to choose from categories_groups_cat1 where offers exist, that's why I use the inner join. I don't know if it is completely correct. If there is another faster(performance) solution I would appreciate it

Comment: 100k rows is nothing. Did you set indices and/or foreign keys for your tables?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  I think the query is too complicated for what you want.  Also, your query has `offers.category_gr` but I don't see that column in the table.

Comment: Why are you doing so many subqueries in your joins? What's the purpose?

Comment: sorry for the mistakes. i would like to select the categories that have offers but these tables are connected through two other tables (categories_vs_groups, categories). row offers.title_gr is connected with categories.title_gr, categories.id with categories_vs_groups.categories_id, categories_vs_groups.categories_groups_cat1_id with categories_groups_cat1.id

Comment: Post the `show create table` ouput off your tables. or post the table and some example data on www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: http://postimg.org/gallery/2dzby59bc/d16027be/ here is some photos of the tables and result

Comment: you can avoid sub-query that creates temp table. This will surely improve performance. Sub-queries that create temp table in memory kills performance, try to avoid as much as you can.

Comment: showing images of data does nothing to help. @RaymondNijland asked for `show create table xxx` for each. We are as blind now as 1hour ago

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid sub-query that creates temp table. This will surely improve performance. Sub-queries that create temp table in memory kills performance, try to avoid as much as you can.

I have modified your code. There may small syntactic errors.

```
  SELECT cat1.id AS cat1id, 
        cat1.title_gr AS title, 
        cat1.order

        FROM categories_groups_cat1 AS cat1

        INNER JOIN 
          categories_groups_cat1_id  AS vs
        ON vs.categories_groups_cat1_id=cat1.id

        INNER JOIN 

            categories
             AS cats
        ON cats.id=vs.categories_id

       INNER JOIN 

            offers

        ON offers.category_gr=cats.title_gr

        GROUP BY cat1.id,cats.title_gr, offers.category_gr
        ORDER BY cat1.order ASC
```